# Topological sort of DAG

Tags: parsing, sorting, compiler-construction, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I have a dag (Tree) in which the directed edges are only of three kinds :

1. Left to right (siblings)
2. Child to Parent
3. Parent to a child

Specifically , the problem is to evaluate an attribute parse tree, but it doesn't matter what the specific problem is.

Sort of :

[image]

**What traversal is guaranteed to give a topological sort of the nodes ?**

I think inorder will fail but some places it is suggested that inorder is the way to go. I know reverse post order woeks on general DAGS but I think there must be a simpler traversal for my case.

Comment: You say it is a "DAG" but you don't show evidence of being a DAG; you describe something that sounds like a plain tree to me.  If it isn't a DAG,  you don't really need to sort it.     Since this is about attribute grammars, maybe you are interested in the dependencies between the attributes?

Comment: @IraBaxter yes its a tree here. I want to sort it such that dependencies are okay. Its an L-attributed grammar's annotated syntax tree.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks for ur earlier answer, it was great.

Answer (score 0):

Since your graph is a DAG, and you therefore have no back-edges, you can use depth-first search to traverse your graph and add nodes to your sorted list in the order in which they come off the DFS stack.